# Hide excluded folders from tree in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

After updating to `IntellijIdea 14` I have discovered that an excluded folder in my project is now visible.

[image: Image of intelliJ folder structure with hidden folder visable]

How do I hide it?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The answer is close, in the Project gear menu:
[image]

**PS:** Yes, it's a self-learning post

Also, you may have switched on the `Show Excluded Files` option. If so, use `Shift` + `Shift` and type *excluded* and do the obvious thing.
[image: show excluded files toggle]

Comment: Does that actually work for you though? In my version of IntelliJ 14, this setting seems to be reset whenever I re-open a project, I've not yet worked out how to make it persistent.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo yes, you're right, in case of  `Reopen` this setting seems to be reset, But if you would open your project by `Open` option, it would work correctly. You should write to IntelliJ support, I think.

Comment: Argh!  Why do I have to do this for every project?  Any way to set this up globally?

Comment: Please indicate in the answer where that menu is. Still pretty frustrating if I can't find the option you're telling me to click.

Comment: No it's really not. A corner of the menu happens to be on the gear button, but there's no indication. I asked my coworker to look at this answer and try to find the menu, and it took him a good 10 minutes. Anyway, I fixed it.

Comment: Note from 2019: the option is not under the `Project` view anymore, it's now under the `Project Files` view; i.e. to hide the files you have to use the drop-down at the top to switch to `Project Files`.

Comment: 7 years later and you are still helping people thanks to this answer! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

Right click at the directory you want to exclude to mark it as excluded, 
[image],
and then **uncheck** the `Show Excluded Files` option.
 [image]

Comment: Checking and unchecking the "Show excluded files" does nothing for me even though I marked folders as excluded.

Answer (score 12):

1: Intellij IDEA > Preferences.

2: Go to File Types.

3: Add *.iml and *.idea to the Ignore files and folders list box at the bottom of this window.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: On Windows I could find "File Types" in : File -> Settings

Comment: Please note that it's `File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types`

Comment: That is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Although this is not exact answer to above question, but it certainly answers my question, so +1 to you Aaron.

Answer (score 2):

In Idea 2022.2.2: project view -> gear icon -> *Tree Appearance* -> *Show Excluded Files*
[image]

Comment: This is greyed out in my case

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to show excluded files instead of hiding them, you can invoke the Find action Window (e.g. `Shift+Shift`), search for `Show Excluded Files` and then turn it on or off. Sometimes there may not be this option in the Find action window somehow (such as me using the version 2019.3.3), but you can still toggle it by adding `<option name="showExcludedFiles" value="true" />` to the node in `.idea/workspace.xml`:

```
<component name="ProjectViewState">
  ...
  <option name="showExcludedFiles" value="true" />
</component>
```

Then restart the project window.